# Ubuntu get MAC addresses all devices also not in network

Tags: ubuntu, mac-address

I have to make a wifi sniffer search for all the devices MAC addresses, even not connected. I need a list of all MAC addresses even not connected.
In particular, I have to know also how many time every MAC address is under the wifi signal and what is the power of the signal.
I have already used the arp-scan -l to search all the devices IP and MAC address connected.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try WireShark for your case.
Here's a link to [wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN) on how to capture WLAN.

When you say that "even not connected", I understand that you want to get MAC Address without being connected to any WLAN interface, which is not posibel to be done.

For traffic monitoring you can use [iftop](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/iftop.8.html), or you can keep up with WireShark.

Comment: Thank you for the reply